# Django Randomly Select List Item to Display In Template

Tags: python, django, list

I have a list of strings in a .py file located in the same dir as my working app. I want to display a randomly selected item from the list and have it display in the template of my app. On each refresh of the page i want the random selection to change. I can't work out how this is possible at the moment.

I'm thinking two things: run a random selection within the .py that has my list; or bring the entire list into the template and then use JS(?) to randomly select an item.

Any advice?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, regarding your two options, I'd go with the former option. It's better to do the randomization in the language that the list originally sits in, otherwise, you'll incur unecessary "serialization" overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Django has a template filter for that: [`random`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#random). You can use it on lists, e.g.:

```
{{ list_of_values|random }}
```

If you ever want to be able to cache the page though, you might want to consider a JavaScript-based solution like you mentioned.

Comment: Hi, how do I get the list into the template html doc? I have now actually saved it as a json file locally on my computer.

Comment: You need to read it into a Python list first (see [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load)) and then pass it to the template as a context variable, e.g. `render(request, 'template.html', {'list_of_values': list_of_values)})`. Go through [part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial03/) of the Django tutorial if you don't know how to use Django templates yet.

Comment: Great, this worked. I created the JSON in my program. Loaded the json in my view and then used this in the template with the '| random' function.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `choices` function from the `random` module.

`views.py`

```py
import random
from somewhere.filename import strings
def index(request):
    return render('template.html', {'list_item', random.choice(strings)})
```